# I am developing Blazor Server app. When I duplicate a tab I get exception "The List of component records is not valid". What to do?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, blazor-server-side

I am developing a Blazor Server app.

There is a Blazor Razor Page which manages News. Recently I applied Save Draft Functionality which temporarily saves data in Radis Cache. When we visit the same page and we find data saved in the cache then the popup asks the user to either Start Fresh or 'Continue Editing'
[Image of the above mentioned Pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCMSV.png)

The Issue is that When I duplicate the above mentioned tab, I get an exception "The List of component records is not valid".
[Image of the Razor Page and The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60QKi.png)

I searched its solutions but the they are related to AzureSignalR but I am using simple SignalR i.e.

```
services.AddSignalR(e => 
{
   e.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 1000;
});
```

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try to add the following to the head of the _Host.chtml page: `@{Response.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-store";}`. If not working, please share more details about your scenario, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: It resolved the Issue. Thanks a lot !!